# What compression is supported by debian file [.deb] decompressor?

Tags: dpkg, deb, tar

I know that a typical .deb file contains three files:

```
debian-binary
control.tar.gz
data.tar.gz
```

and that some are xz compressed instead of gzip (control.tar.xz, data.tar.xz).

What are other compression supported for debian files?
And how does debian installer knows which decompression to use?

If I want to add support for another compression (for example, zopfli - https://github.com/google/zopfli). Is there source code for debian installer available which I could modify to make this addition possible?

Comment: I'm not sure how you view zopfli as another compression, it generates compressed streams of a few formats that are fully compatible with the original formats. For any files that are compressed by the user you could recompress them yourself. For the rest, unless if dpkg links directly to compression libraries you could just replace the programs used by dpkg and/or tar with a wrapper that compress with zopfli (decompression should be the same). Let me know if you'd like me to extend that as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [this blog post](https://raphaelhertzog.com/2010/09/17/how-to-create-debian-packages-with-alternative-compression-methods/), it seems `dpkg-deb` handles compression. And from `man dpkg-deb` for [14.04](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/dpkg-deb.1.html):

```
-Zcompress-type
      Specify  which  compression type to use when building a package.
      Allowed values are gzip, xz, bzip2, lzma, and none  (default  is
      xz).
```

In [15.10](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man1/dpkg-deb.1.html):

```
-Zcompress-type
      Specify which compression type to use when building  a  package.
      Allowed   values   are  gzip,  xz  (since  dpkg  1.15.6),  bzip2
      (deprecated), lzma (since dpkg  1.14.0;  deprecated),  and  none
      (default is xz).
```

And in [22.04](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/dpkg-deb.1.html), with `lzma` and `bzip2` gone and `zstd` added:

```
-Zcompress-type
   Specify which compression type to use when building a package.  Allowed values are
   gzip, xz (since dpkg 1.15.6), zstd (since dpkg 1.19.0.5ubuntu2) and none (default is
   zstd).
```

The source code for `dpkg` can be browsed at [Debian Alioth](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/dpkg/dpkg.git/). From what I can tell, it also uses `tar` in places, and if `tar` doesn't support zopfli, get ready to add support for zopfli to [GNU tar](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/) as well.

Comment: Zstd support for dpkg has beed added to Debian Bookworm (12.0), available as of dpkg v1.21.18. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/669004/zst-compression-not-supported-by-apt-dpkg

Comment: @ThomasGuyot-Sionnest interesting, thanks! I have updated the post